# page view counter filter by date

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to have a simple counter for page view something like :

```
Page View :250
Unique Viewer: 150
```

i tried this :

```
id
page view
page unique view
```

...

```
if(user is unique)
{
+1 to page view and unique view
}
else
{
just +1 to page view
}
```

but this will show all views

i don't know which tables and fields i need, i want to show just for today.
as you know with my table and fields i will have all visits, but i want just today's visits.

what table and filed's i need?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are asking.  Your psudo code shows what you are trying to achieve, but you mention you cannot store the data?  Could you explain yourself a little more?

Comment: No no, i know c# and entityframework, but i dont know which tables and fileds i need to store data to show daily visits, as i mentioned i need to show daily but my solution is about showing all visits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are doing +1 to your hits so all you have is a total.

What you need is an individual row for every page hit. So you can have a table similar to  this:

```
TABLE PageViews
-----
[id]
[userId]
[ip]
[logTime]
[page]
```

For every page view, you insert a new row. Log the `userId` if they are logged in, log the IP, log the page they were on, etc...

When you want totals, you can query your data by page, date, user, etc... group by IP for unique.